# Iron Router BaseController undefined when deployed?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My app runs fine locally, but when I deploy it on xxxx.meteor.com, I'm getting the Iron Router "Organize your Meteor application" splash page. Additionally, once the browser hits the first `Basecontroller.extend({`, I get a ref. error that "BaseController is not defined". Maybe something to do with the load order of the route controller specific to deployment? This is my code:

client/main/routes.js

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'splash',
    controller: 'SplashController'
});

Router.route('/login', {
    name: 'login',
    controller: 'LoginController'
});

Router.route('/home', {
    name: 'home',
    controller: 'HomeController'

//...etc
```

client/main/controller.js

```
BaseController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    requiresAuth: false,
    publicOnly: false,
    // Called before anything happens
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        if (!Meteor.userId() && this.requiresAuth) {
            return this.redirect('/login');
        }
        if (Meteor.userId() && this.publicOnly) {
            return this.redirect('/home');
        }
    }
});
```

client/(all templates)/controller.js

```
TemplateController = BaseController.extend({
    requiresAuth: false,
    publicOnly: true,
    action: function () {
        this.render('template', {
            to: 'content'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue belong in loading only. So, code which should always load first, try put inside `<app-root>\lib` directory.

Like your case, put `route.js` and `controller.js` inside `lib` directory.

Read more about loading order in meteor - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp